# Property of some composite Mersenne numbers

Tags: number-theory, mersenne-numbers

I noticed this property of some composite Mersenne numbers:

If $p$ is prime, $p=1 \bmod 4$ and $(1+6 \cdot p)$ is prime

for a theorem of Fermat every prime $p=1 \bmod 3$ can be written as $p=c^2+3 \cdot d^2$

then $$(1+6 \cdot p)=a^2+3 \cdot b^2$$

if $b=0 \bmod 3$ for a properties of the cubic residues  $\left( \frac{2}{(1+6 \cdot p)} \right)_3=1$

then $$2^p-1=0\mod(1+6 \cdot p)$$

**Example**

$p=37$ , $(1+6 \cdot p)=223=14^2+3\cdot 3^2$

$(2^{37}-1)=0  \bmod 223$

**Question**

Is this result always true?

Comment: You can use `\bmod` to get proper spacing around the binary $\bmod$ operator. The `\mod` command is for spacing at the end of an equation, such as in your last equation. Also, you can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs.

Answer (score 0):

In $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_3]=\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$, if $q \equiv 1\bmod 6$ is a prime number then $\Bbb{F}_q[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ isn't an integral domain thus $(q)$ isn't a prime ideal,  and since $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_3]$ is a PID it means 
$(q)= (a+b\sqrt{-3})(a-b\sqrt{-3})$ and
$\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_3]/(a+b\sqrt{-3}) \cong \Bbb{F}_q$.

> Iff $2$ is a cube and a square in $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_3]/(a+b\sqrt{-3})$ then it is a $6$-th power in  $\Bbb{F}_q$ so that $2^{(q-1)/6}\equiv 1\bmod q $ and $q\ | \ 2^{(q-1)/6}-1$.

Quadratic reciprocity says $2$ is a square when $q\equiv \pm 1\bmod 8$,

Cubic reciprocity says $2$ is a cube when $3|b$.